# YouTrack (Jetbrains) copies cards into new board

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I am using myjetbrains' online interface and when I create a new board, all the other swimlanes and tasks from previous board gets copied into new one.

I couldn't find how to connect a task / card into a specific agile board as well.

How can I resolve this problem?
How can I connect a task / card to a specific agile board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a board you can choose what projects should be reflected on the board. Meaning several boards may be configured identically and show similar issues. To check board's settings, please refer to Agile settings> board's name (left corner)> check/uncheck target projects.
Please note, you can also configure how swimlames should be identified or whether should be disabled at all.